# Attempt to de-reference a null object in loop

Tags: apex

I'm trying to loop through a list of Child objects where I grabbed the Id of the parent and add those to a list so I can update the parents. I'm getting an "Attempt to de-reference a null object" error in my loop after the first System.debug below. I understand what the error means, but I'm not sure how it's applying here since the debug log is displaying values and I've declared my variable. I don't make it to the second Debug log listed below so it has to be in those three lines, right? Any help?

```
  //Puts the Opportunity Program's Opportunity ID into a distinct Set
    if(opptyProgramList != Null){
        for(Opportunity_Program__c op : opptyProgramList){

            System.debug('In loop: ' + op.Id + ' : ' + op.Opportunity__r.Id);
            Opportunity newOpportunity;
            newOpportunity.Id = op.Opportunity__r.Id;
            newOpportunity.GRI_Notification_Queued__c = date.today();
            System.debug('OpportunityToAdd: ' + newOpportunity);
            opportunitySet.Add(newOpportunity);
        }
```

Comment: sfdcfox answered it perfectly, but how are you building opptyProgramList?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't initialize newOpportunity. You need to initialize a variable before you can use it:

```
Opportunity newOpportunity = new Opportunity();
```

As an aside, I strongly recommend that you don't use `__r.Id`, but instead stick with the lookup field directly.

```
newOpportunityId = op.Opportunity__c;
```

Comment: Curiously, why don't you recommend using `__r.Id`?

Comment: @DanJones It's a matter of efficiency. `__c` is easier to type, uses fewer characters against the character limits, easier to read, uses less CPU time, and uses less heap space. There's some limited times when you'd want to use `__r.Id` in a query (when other fields are included), but there's never a situation where `__r.Id` would be somehow better than simply using `__c` in an assignment like this.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you! I figured it was something simple. @sfdcfox I've seen others suggest on here the format I used initially. What's the difference?

As for the __r.Id, I had the __c originally, but was running into issues. When I changed it, it set me up for the next round of errors to work through. I'll try and change it back to see if it was something else that I did not realizing. Thank you very much!

Comment: @ScottWalker Make sure your query is also using `__c` if that's the case. Also, you'll probably want to make sure, either way, that the field is not null, otherwise you'd get an "update without id" error.

Comment: @sfdcfox That does make sense. I'll add that in though it is a Master-Detail so (theoretically) it shouldn't be able to exist without its Master. I've seen crazier things though. Thanks a ton! I'm still figuring out APEX as I've only used scripting languages in the past.